# Calculating the angle tilt using only accelerometers

Tags: math, accelerometer, angle

I would like to know how to calculate using the coordinates of the accelerometer of my Android phone the angle between the two segments connecting the accelerometer and the bottom of the tree (B) and the accelerometer and the top of the tree (T) .

[image: sketch]

The accelerometer takes a value of acceleration on 3 axes every second, so I calculated the average and I have:
For the phone towards B: Ay1 = -9.69m.s^-1 and Az1 = 0.71m.s^-1
For the phone towards T: Ay2 = -9.71m.s^-1 and Az2 = 0.71m.s^-1

I am located at a distance D = 20m from the tree.
I would like at the end to know the value of H. So I would like to know how to calculate the angle and then find the height of the tree.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The angles we need are the angles between world-up and device-up. Since the gravity vector is pointing towards world-down, this is simply (assuming, you are pointing with the device y-axis):

```
cos angle = -a.y / sqrt(a.x^2 + a.y^2 + a.z^2)
```

The two angles we get from your readings are:

```
angle1 = 4.19065°
angle2 = 4.18205°
```

You can already see that the angles are very close as the two acceleration values are also extremely close. Btw, I wonder if you are really pointing with the y-axis because the gravity values suggest that you are holding the phone almost upright in both cases.

Anyway, if we assume that the two angles are correct, we can now calculate the height of the respective triangles assuming a length to target `l`. Then:

```
tan (90° - angle) = h / l
```

Assuming `l=20 m`, this gives us two height values:

```
h1 = 272.958 m
h2 = 273.521 m
```

These are heights above the height of the phone. In theory, one should be positive and the other should be negative. The height of the tree would be the difference of the two heights:

```
treeH = h2 - h1
treeH = 0.56338 m
```

As you have seen throughout the example, your readings must be pretty off. Nevertheless, this is how you would calculate the tree height.